# How to measure velocity of Table View's scrolling?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I'd like to call or not call a method depending on how fast user has scrolled.

It has to be instantly measured as user's finger goes because the method needs to be either called or ignored the second it starts moving, not when it has stopped.

Comment: Have you looked at the methods for `UIScrollViewDelegate`?

Comment: ah.. thank you again. got it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me.

```
CGPoint scrollVelocity = [[self.tableView panGestureRecognizer] velocityInView:self.tableView];
NSLog(@"scroll velocity : %f",scrollVelocity.y);
```

Comment: i cannot get velocity , it says 0,0 all the time :(

Answer (score 0):

This method exposes the velocity value. It is part of the scroll view delegate.

```
optional func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, 
                       withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, 
                targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>){
}
```